# Bounty option is not available

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I asked a question on Stack Overflow but did not receive any answers. I know that there is a bounty option available. However for some reason it does not appear anymore. Could it be that I can only create bounty only on questions with no answers at all? Even if the answer is unsatisfying?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you talk about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766129/eclipse-doesnt-switch-to-perl-module-file-view-while-debugging), wait for a while.

You cannot set bounty if:

> The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a
>   chance to answer your question normally first.
>
> *(from [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties))*

Additionally, you have to have more than 75 reputation, but looks like you've passed that requirement.

And no, even if there are some answers already, you **can** set bounty (for example, to award existing answers). You can view any old enough (maybe not yours) answer and you should see a "start a bounty" button.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Actually what seemed strange to me is the fact that the bounty related line DID appear there before and looked something like this:

      _question eligible for bounty in x hours_

But then it just disappeared after one answer was added..

Comment: @EugeneS like other "tips" here, it disappears on certain conditions. Might be possible to start a feature request asking to leave this message even when answers are added.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Hi. Can you please explain to which "tips" do you refer? Also could you please explain how is it possible to start a feature request? Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneS write here (on MSO) a post describing what you want and file it with [meta-tag:feature-request] tag

Comment: @EugeneS no official documentation, but I mean things like "Please add a comment explaining the downvote" when you downvote posts and have less than X points (think it's 1000) - kind of "tutorial" to help people around until they're familiar enough with the place to handle things by themselves.